# Phonegap 3.5 - Android 4.4 - Get file extension from the getPicture() function

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

In Android versions prior to 4.4, when you used the "photolibrary" option to the getPicture function, it would return a file with a file extension like this:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function(fileURI) {
    var fileName = imageURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1; // used to have extension attached
    .
    .
    .
```

In Android 4.4, it seems that has been removed.  That substring no longer includes the extenstion.  Where can you get that from in the callback or is a PhoneGap oversight?